# Can not load background image in flask HTML template

Tags: python, html, css, flask, ngrok

i am working on a flask app, i am trying to load background image through my HTML template but it can not load. How ever i get following HTTP response:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2022 09:54:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Aug/2022 09:54:23] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Following is my `app.py file`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_from_directory
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
app= Flask(__name__,template_folder = r'/flask_projects/app2/templates/',static_folder = r'/flask_projects/app2/static/') 
FAVICON_URL='https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-17/50e4281252565f8fc85151c075d4e937.ico'
@app.route("/") 
def symptom(): 
    return render_template('Copy of symptoms_result.html')

@app.route("/detector", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def code_detector():
 if request.method == 'POST':
   return render_template('Copy of symptoms_result.html', prediction_text = 'The ICD Code is: {}'.format(response))

if __name__  == '__main__':
  run_with_ngrok(app)
app.run()
```

following is `styles.css`

```
{   
    background-image: url("Penguins.png");
    background-size: cover; /* or contain depending on what you want */
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
}
```

following is `Copy of symptoms_result.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='styles.css')}}">
</head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
</hmtl>
```

**I get following HTTP response with blank output screen**

[image]
[image]

Comment: _"following is styles.css"_ - why is there no _selector_?

Comment: you mean body{ } or .background? i have tried that too, i get same output.

Comment: What body, your template doesn't even contain one :-) The browser will of course automatically create one (but meta tags outside of head are still wrong) - but since there is not content, it will likely not have any height either. Try applying it to html instead.

Comment: Also, have you checked what the browser console has to say yet? Is the image actually located in the same folder, as the stylesheet?

Comment: yes it is in same folder

Comment: i have tried to load image in html template too, but could not get success.

Comment: When you inspect the element you tried to apply this to using your browser dev tools, do you see your rule from the stylesheet apply? And, again, does the browser console have to say anything?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to load background directly in my html file, it resolved the issue.
I used following code in my html file, now my background image gets loaded successfully.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
<style> 
body {
  background-image: url("/static/Penguins.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```